# What is the most elegant Ruby statement to split a string in its characters taking two by two?

Tags: ruby

I have the string `"abigword"` and I want to take the array `["ab", "ig", "wo", "rd"]`. To generalize, given a string, I want to take the array of its constituent characters paired two-by-two.

What is the most elegant Ruby way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
"abigword".scan(/../) # => ["ab", "ig", "wo", "rd"]
```

It can also handle odd number of chars if you want:

```
"abigwordf".scan(/..?/) # => ["ab", "ig", "wo", "rd", "f"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Two non-regexp versions:

```
#1:
p "abigword".chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join) #=> ["ab", "ig", "wo", "rd"]

#2:
s, a = "abigword", []
a << s.slice!(0,2) until s.empty?
p a #=> ["ab", "ig", "wo", "rd"]
```

Comment: more readable a << s[0..2] until s.empty?

Comment: Works fine for me in both Ruby 1.9 and 2.0. Note the "!". unlike the slice-method, the slice! modifies the string, making it shorter.

Comment: @hirolau: it was a reply to a comment of Monk_Code :)